Given $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Omega) \setminus L^\infty(\Omega)$, does it follow that $A \cap S(f,K) \neq \emptyset$ for all $K > 0$?
Context. Throughout this post I will be dealing with the Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb R^n$. Moreover, I denote the measure of a measurable set $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ by $|E|$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ stands for an arbitrary non-empty open set.
Question. Consider an arbitrary function $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ such that $f \notin L^\infty(\Omega)$. For each $K > 0$, define the sets
$$ A = \Bigg\{ x \in \Omega : \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{|B(x,r) \cap \Omega|} \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^p \, dy = |f(x)|^p \Bigg\} $$
and
$$ S(f,K) := \{ x \in \Omega : |f(x)| > K \},$$
My goal is to prove that
$$ A \cap S(f,K) \neq \emptyset, \quad \text{ for all }K > 0.$$
My attempt. Unfortunately I don't think I was able to make great progress on this problem but I made two observations that I think that might be crucial. First, since $f \notin L^\infty(\Omega)$, it is clear that
$$ |S(f,K)| > 0, \quad \text{ for all } K > 0.$$
On the other hand, since $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, we have that $|f|^p \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$. Hence, by the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem for open sets we have that
$$ \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{|B(x,r) \cap \Omega|} \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^p \, dy = |f(x)|^p, \quad \text{ for almost all } x \in \Omega. $$
In other words, this last conclusion tells us that almost every point of $\Omega$ belongs to $A$. But from here I don't know how to proceed.
Thanks for any help in advance.

If $A$ and $B$ are two Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\Omega$ then $$|B|=|B\cap A|  + |B\cap A^c|$$ Your last observation tells you something about $|B\cap A^c|$.

@Michael Thanks for your comment. I think I understood your hint, but I would like for you to confirm my arguments. My last observation tells me that $| A^c | = 0$. Hence, since $S(f,K) \cap A^c \subset A^c$, we also obtain that $|S(f,K) \cap A^c| = 0$. Consequently, by using the formula you provided it follows that $$ |S(f,K)| = |S(f,K) \cap A| + |S(f,K) \cap A^c| = |S(f,K) \cap A|. $$ Moreover, by hypothesis we have that $|S(f,K)| > 0$ and so we conclude that $|S(f,K) \cap A| > 0$, which in turn implies that $$ S(f,K) \cap A \neq \emptyset, $$ and this is obviously valid for all $K > 0$.

Looks good. Yes, you use $B=S(f,K)$ in this case.

@Michael Thanks for your help. If you care about elaborating an answer, please do. I would gladly mark it as the right one.

This answer just replicates my comment: For any two sets $A,B$ we can write $B$ as a disjoint union
$$ B = (B\cap A) \cup (B \cap A^c)$$
If we know the sets $A,B$ are Lebesgue measurable we know $A^c$, $B\cap A$ and $B\cap A^c$ are also Lebesgue measurable and so
$$|B| = |B\cap A|+|B\cap A^c|$$
If we also know $|A^c|=0$ then we can conclude $|B|=|B\cap A|$.
